Angular FormControlName vs NgModel Binding
I have a general question using Angular's FormgroupName or NgModel.  The Docs I  am reading say NgModel was deprecated in Version 6, but it is still available in 17/18, today's current version. The beauty of NgModel is that I am getting instant binding back to my data model, but using the FormgroupName requires me to do manually update like this:
  this.account.company = this.profileForm.controls["company"].value;

Is there a way to bind the fields of a FormGroup like we do with ngModel, or is updating each field manually the norm?
Thanks

You could use signals. In a way, you still have to write code to set the value in your variable while using reactive forms over ngModel, but with signals, you can make it declarative instead of imperative.
form = new FormGroup({
  control: new FormControl(''),
});
controlValue = toSignal(this.form.get("control").valueChanges);

That way, it would be easy to add something like a debounce:
controlValue = toSignal(this.form.get("control").valueChanges.pipe(debounceTime(200)));

*Edit: I forgot to specify; toSignal is a utility imported from the rxjs-interop module:
import { toSignal } from '@angular/core/rxjs-interop';

First you need to understand the different between reactive and template driven approach
What are the practical differences between template-driven and reactive forms?
You have to choose based on your requirement

If you need dynamic page, use reactive approach(NgModel not necessary)


static page, use template driven  (ngModel required)

